# Angular mat-list-item routerLink not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am not getting why the routing doesn't work. Any help please...

1. When I click on "Terminal 1/2/3" (please check the below picture) it doesn't show the Terminal page
2. When 'AF' is collapse, there is a big gap between AF and Dashboard in menu

Code: [github.com/sid-ca/Configurator](http://github.com/sid-ca/Configurator)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-1b3qtp-vhyry6

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/github/sid-ca/Configurator

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
```

**index.html**

```html
<base href="/">
<app-root></app-root>
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<app-header></app-header>
    
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened="true" style="min-width:60px; background: #F3F3F3;" autosize fixedTopGap="56">
        <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
    </mat-sidenav>
    
    <mat-sidenav-content [@onSideNavChange]="sidebarState">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { TerminalComponent } from './af/terminal/terminal.component';
    
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: 'terminal', component: TerminalComponent }
];
    
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**sidebar.component.html**

```html
<div class="sidebar_menu" [@onSideNavChange]="sidebarState">
    <mat-nav-list class="menu-list">
        <mat-list-item (click)="showSubmenu = !showSubmenu" class="parent" routerLinkActive="active-list-item"
            routerLink="login" title="af">
            <mat-icon class="icon menu-icon" style="font-size: 1em !important;" [@iconAnimation]="sidebarState">input
            </mat-icon>
            <mat-icon class="menu-button" [ngClass]="{'rotated' : showSubmenu}" *ngIf="isExpanded || isShowing">
                expand_more</mat-icon>
            <span class="label" [@labelAnimation]="sidebarState">AF</span>
        </mat-list-item>
        <div class="submenu" [ngClass]="{'expanded' : showSubmenu}" *ngIf="isShowing || isExpanded">
            <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'terminal'">Terminal 1</a>
            <a mat-list-item routerLink="terminal" routerLinkActive="active">Terminal 2</a>
            <a routerLink="terminal">
                <mat-list-item> Terminal 3 </mat-list-item>
            </a>
```

**terminal.component.html**

```html
<div class="main_container" style=" height:100vh;">
    <p>terminal works!</p>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: So which routing is not working?

Comment: > When I click on "Terminal 1/2/3" it does show the Terminal page, 
you mean this is not working?

Comment: @Derek.W - Added the picture, Terminal 1 or 2 or 3 (those 3 sub menus)

Comment: @WilliamWang - That's correct, When I  click on Terminal 1, it is not displaying the content in terminal.component.html

Comment: Try to add `/` in routerLink so `/terminal`

Comment: @Derek.W - I did try that, no luck :(

Comment: Can you attach your codebase as snippet and post link here?

Comment: That link does not contain code parts.

Comment: trying to upload again

Comment: src folder doesn't exist

Comment: except .scss file, hopefully all other files should be there now. not sure why it doesn't upload .scss  files

Comment: I got this error. > The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.

Comment: try to upload files correctly and let me know

Comment: @WilliamWang - github.com/sid-ca/Configurator

Comment: 1. check the console to see if there is any error messages that might help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code which is why it is not working as expected.

> When I click on "Terminal 1/2/3" (please check the below picture) it
> doesn't show the Terminal page

well it doesn't work becuase

1. You have wrong links. Router link should say `/terminal` as configured in your routing module.

```
<a mat-list-item routerLink="/terminal">Terminal 1</a>
<a mat-list-item routerLink="/terminal" routerLinkActive="active">Terminal 2</a>
<a routerLink="/terminal"> <mat-list-item> Terminal 3 </mat-list-item></a>
```

2. `sidebar.module.ts` need to import `RouterModule` for `routerLink` attributes to work.

> When 'AF' is collapse, there is a big gap between AF and Dashboard in menu

That has to do with your `ngIf` condition. You should either set correct value for `isShowing` in component file of update `ngIf`

```
<div
      class="submenu"
      [ngClass]="{'expanded' : showSubmenu}"
      *ngIf="showSubmenu && (isShowing || isExpanded)">
  ...
</div>
```

Take a look at updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-c8jajv).

Answer (score 2):

General answer:
In case anywhere in the application component if `routerLink` not working

then check its related `###.module.ts` file and check RouterModule is imported or not.

If not then Add `import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';`
in `####.module.ts` file.

And your routerLink will start working!!!

Answer (score 1):

1. check the console to see if there are any error messages that might help (before and after clicking on links)
2. type terminal directly in the browser address bar to see if the terminal page really works
3. you do need the `/` before the path: `routerLink='/terminal'`

Comment: 1. No error in console, 2. /terminal in browser works, 3) Already tried routerLink='/terminal'

Comment: then the only possibility seems to be some issue with your links click event! try to bind click for one of them to a function that logs some text in the console and see if it works

Comment: it is a hyperlink, I don't understand what to fix in click event

Comment: I just want to make sure you are able to click that! remove routerLink and add (click)="someFunction()" to see if it fires click event or not. as it might be covered by an invisible element or something!

Comment: it is clickable, I have updated my post with github url

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `RouterModule` (from `@angular/router`) in your `SidebarModule`. Otherwise Angular doesn't know what do with `routerLink` attribute.

In fact, if you used input binding for routerLink instead of using it as a static attribute, you would get a helpful compiler error from Angular:

```
// sidebar.component.html
<a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'terminal'">Terminal 1</a>

// error triggered
Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("howSubmenu}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try importing

```
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own custom side-item.component

side-item.component.html :

```
   <mat-list-item class="touchable text-hover-gray" (click)="switch()">
  <span class="material-icons-outlined icon" matListItemIcon>{{
    item.icon
  }}</span>
  <div matListItemTitle (click)="item.action()">{{ item.title }}</div>
  <div>
    <span class="material-icons" *ngIf="getExpand()">expand_less</span>
    <span class="material-icons" *ngIf="!getExpand()">expand_more</span>
  </div>
</mat-list-item>
<mat-list *ngIf="getExpand()">
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of item.subItems" class="touchable text-hover-gray">
      <div matListItemTitle (click)="item.action()">{{ item.title }}</div>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

side-item.component.ts :

```
  import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';


export interface sideSubItem{
  title:string;
  action:Function
}

export interface sideItem{
  icon :string,
  title:string,
  action:Function,
  subItems:sideSubItem[]
} 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-side-item',
  templateUrl: './side-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-item.component.scss']
})
export class SideItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() item !:sideItem;
  private expand : boolean=false;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  switch(){
    this.expand = !this.expand;
  }
  getExpand(){
    return this.expand;
  }
}
```

result :

[image]